# mutating a new variable by 7 column values, repetitive but long code

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I shorten this code? I have multiple fracture categories to go through. But, it is repetitive. How can I shorten it.

```
    frax_older   <- frax_older %>%
  mutate(
    fracture_type = case_when(
      diagnosis_1 == "femur head" | diagnosis_2 == "femur head" |
      diagnosis_3 == "femur head" | diagnosis_4 == "femur head" |
      diagnosis_5 == "femur head" | diagnosis_6 == "femur head" |
      diagnosis_7 == "femur head" ~ "femur head",
        
      diagnosis_1 == "femur subtrochanteric" | diagnosis_2 == "femur subtrochanteric" |
      diagnosis_3 == "femur subtrochanteric" | diagnosis_4 == "femur subtrochanteric" |
      diagnosis_5 == "femur subtrochanteric" | diagnosis_6 == "femur subtrochanteric" |
      diagnosis_7 == "femur subtrochanteric" ~ "femur subtrochanteric",   
        
      diagnosis_1 == "femur neck" | diagnosis_2 == "femur neck" |
      diagnosis_3 == "femur neck" | diagnosis_4 == "femur neck" |
      diagnosis_5 == "femur neck" | diagnosis_6 == "femur neck" |
      diagnosis_7 == "femur neck" ~ "femur neck",
      .
      .
      .          
       
    )
  )
```

Comment: Are there a mix of values in the various `diagnosis_x` columns, or are they blanks? It would be helpful if you can provide a reproducible data example so we can work with a sample of data exactly like yours. That's often easiest using something like `dput(head(frax_older))` and pasting the output into your question.

Comment: Each diagnosis column has only one diagnosis value.

Comment: Are the other values NA or blanks?

Comment: If an observation doesn't have multiple diagnoses, NAs are filled from diagnosis_2 to _7. Al observations have a value for diagnosis_1.

Comment: Can you please post a few rows of your data as sample

Comment: First I do not think the code is correct. For example, think of the first row being `femur_head` fro diagnosis_1 and `femur_neck` for diagnosis_2. What should be the expected output?? Now you see why the code is wrong?

Comment: IThe code is correct. But, it is a bit long. My wish was to shorten it. I have to use something like this. 
`frax_older <- frax_older %>%
rowwise() %>% 
mutate(
    fracture_type = case_when(
    "femur head" %in% c(diagnosis_1, diagnosis_2, diagnosis_3, 
                                              diagnosis_4, diagnosis_5, diagnosis_6, 
                                              diagnosis_7)~"femur head"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can further be shortened.  Demonstrated below on a sample data created

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              case = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L),
       diagnosis_1 = c("femur subtrochanteric",
                       "femur subtrochanteric","Other1","Other1"),
       diagnosis_2 = c("Other1", "femur subtrochanteric", "Other2", "Other2"),
       diagnosis_3 = c("femur head",
                       "femur subtrochanteric","Other3","Other3"),
       diagnosis_4 = c("Other1", "femur subtrochanteric", "Other4", "Other4"),
       diagnosis_5 = c("Other2",
                       "femur subtrochanteric","femur neck","Other5"),
       diagnosis_6 = c("Other3", "femur subtrochanteric", "Other5", "Other6"),
       diagnosis_7 = c("Other4", "Other1", "Other6", "Other7")
)
df
#>   case           diagnosis_1           diagnosis_2           diagnosis_3
#> 1    1 femur subtrochanteric                Other1            femur head
#> 2    2 femur subtrochanteric femur subtrochanteric femur subtrochanteric
#> 3    3                Other1                Other2                Other3
#> 4    4                Other1                Other2                Other3
#>             diagnosis_4           diagnosis_5           diagnosis_6 diagnosis_7
#> 1                Other1                Other2                Other3      Other4
#> 2 femur subtrochanteric femur subtrochanteric femur subtrochanteric      Other1
#> 3                Other4            femur neck                Other5      Other6
#> 4                Other4                Other5                Other6      Other7

library(tidyverse)

df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(fracture_type = case_when(any(str_detect(c_across(starts_with('diagnosis')), 'femur head')) ~ 'femur head',
                                   any(str_detect(c_across(starts_with('diagnosis')), 'femur subtrochanteric')) ~ 'femur subtrochanteric',
                                   any(str_detect(c_across(starts_with('diagnosis')), 'femur neck')) ~ 'femur neck',
                                   TRUE ~ 'other'))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 9
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    case diagnosis_1  diagnosis_2 diagnosis_3 diagnosis_4 diagnosis_5 diagnosis_6
#>   <int> <chr>        <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
#> 1     1 femur subtr~ Other1      femur head  Other1      Other2      Other3     
#> 2     2 femur subtr~ femur subt~ femur subt~ femur subt~ femur subt~ femur subt~
#> 3     3 Other1       Other2      Other3      Other4      femur neck  Other5     
#> 4     4 Other1       Other2      Other3      Other4      Other5      Other6     
#> # ... with 2 more variables: diagnosis_7 <chr>, fracture_type <chr>
```

check it

```r
df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(fracture_type = case_when(any(str_detect(c_across(starts_with('diagnosis')), 'femur head')) ~ 'femur head',
                                   any(str_detect(c_across(starts_with('diagnosis')), 'femur subtrochanteric')) ~ 'femur subtrochanteric',
                                   any(str_detect(c_across(starts_with('diagnosis')), 'femur neck')) ~ 'femur neck',
                                   TRUE ~ 'other')) %>% as.data.frame()
#>   case           diagnosis_1           diagnosis_2           diagnosis_3
#> 1    1 femur subtrochanteric                Other1            femur head
#> 2    2 femur subtrochanteric femur subtrochanteric femur subtrochanteric
#> 3    3                Other1                Other2                Other3
#> 4    4                Other1                Other2                Other3
#>             diagnosis_4           diagnosis_5           diagnosis_6 diagnosis_7
#> 1                Other1                Other2                Other3      Other4
#> 2 femur subtrochanteric femur subtrochanteric femur subtrochanteric      Other1
#> 3                Other4            femur neck                Other5      Other6
#> 4                Other4                Other5                Other6      Other7
#>           fracture_type
#> 1            femur head
#> 2 femur subtrochanteric
#> 3            femur neck
#> 4                 other
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could make the code less verbose by first creating a collapsed version containing all diagnosis in one string per row and then using `grepl` inside `dplyr::case_when`.

Example code:

```
library(dplyr)

frax_older <- frax_older %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(diagnosis_all = paste(c_across(starts_with("diagnosis")), collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(fracture_type = case_when(
           grepl("femur head", diagnosis_all) ~ "femur head",
           grepl("femur subtrochanteric", diagnosis_all) ~ "femur subtrochanteric",
           grepl("femur neck", diagnosis_all) ~ "femur neck",
           .
           .
           .
         ))
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you very much indeed! I thought about using paste() and str_detect. But, grepl() didn't come to my mind.

Comment: `str_detect` works perfectly fine as well!